# How to Reuse One Menu-bar Code in one HTML file Into all web HTML pages

Tags: html, css, web, master-pages, menubar

I am a beginner and making some web pages using HTML and CSS. I am facing a problem with menu bar and need the solution. Basically I want to display same Menu bar and background  in all the web pages but not by copying their code again and again in the html files. I want to keep a separate file having Menu bar ,style and background code and run it in all HTML pages by calling its code from inside of all other HTML files. pls help

Comment: Master pages are a technology specific to ASP.NET. Are you using ASP.NET? You'll need some kind of server-side technology. This question is quite broad right now, so if I were you, I'd do some more research, and if you run into problems implementing a specific technology, then we can help.

Answer (score -1):

You should write the menu code to the index.html and in this file you should use an iframe tag to refer tho the other subpages.